# Automatically delete files older than 3 hours macOS

Tags: macos

I have a camera setup up to take an image every few seconds and then the image is processed and is no longer required. Can anyone help me to write a script/service that will delete files/images in a folder that are older than 3 hours? I'm trying to do this as it takes a ton of space if only purged every 24 hours using Automator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example `find` command that you can modify to suit your needs:

```bash
find '/path/to/files/' -type f -name '*.jpg' -mmin +180 -delete
```

I'd use `launchd` to *run* it every 3 hours.

Here is an example `.plist` *file* that will run the `find` *command* every 3 hours using `launchd`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.my.delete.every.three.hours</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/find</string>
        <string>/path/to/files/</string>
        <string>-type</string>
        <string>f</string>
        <string>-name</string>
        <string>*.jpg</string>
        <string>-mmin</string>
        <string>+180</string>
        <string>-delete</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <false/>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>10800</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

It would be saved in: `$HOME/Library/LaunchAgents/com.my.delete.every.three.hours.plist`

From **Terminal**:

```bash
touch "$HOME/Library/LaunchAgents/com.my.delete.every.three.hours.plist"
open -e "$HOME/Library/LaunchAgents/com.my.delete.every.three.hours.plist"
```

- Copy and paste example **XML** *code* into the opened **TextEdit** *document*:
- Modify as needed:

  - E.g. Change `/path/to/files/` to the actual *path*.
  - E.g. Change `*.jpg` to the proper extension if not: `jpg`
- Save and close the document.

Continue in **Terminal**, to *load* the `plist` *file*:

```bash
launchctl load "$HOME/Library/LaunchAgents/com.my.delete.every.three.hours.plist"
```

To `stop` and `unload` the `"$HOME/Library/LaunchAgents/com.my.delete.every.three.hours.plist"` *file* use:

```bash
launchctl stop "$HOME/Library/LaunchAgents/com.my.delete.every.three.hours.plist"
launchctl unload "$HOME/Library/LaunchAgents/com.my.delete.every.three.hours.plist"
```

Comment: Holy smoke, it’d be shorter in Perl...

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica The actual code is the first snippet only, the rest is to have it run automatically by launchd.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) script that is executed by a [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job to run at any frequency that you need (e.g., every minute, every hour, etc.). You'll need to build the bash script - some of the things you probably need are:

1. [Find old files](http://www.dba-oracle.com/linux/finding_files_by_age.htm)
2. [Delete files returned from find command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167823/find-exec-rm-vs-delete)

Comment: Note that `cron` is deprecated in macOS and has been since the release of Mac OS X 10.4; `launchd` is the preferred method (and eventually the only method) for running this sort of script.